# Django template iterate over context list

Tags: python, django

I can't find a clear answer on this.  I have a view that shows multiple models.  In my template, I have written out everything to manually display what I want but it doesn't really stick to DRY so I'd like to iterate over the context.  What I can't find is what the context object is referenced as in my template?  I have written pseudo code in the template snippet below of what I want to achieve.

Edited to simplify: The code in the template works in Django shell but not in the template

template.html

```
{% for object in object_list %}
    {% for key, value in object.items %}
        {% if key == 'string' %}
             <h2>{{ value }}</h2>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

views.py

```
class ConfigurationDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    ''' Returns a view of all the models in a configuration '''
    template_name = 'configurator/configuration_detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ''' Uses a list of dictionaries containing plural strings and models to
        filter by the configuration ID to only show items in the config. '''
        context = super(ConfigurationDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context_dict = [
            {'string':'integrations', 'model': IntegrationInstance},
            {'string':'control_groups', 'model':  ControlGroup},
            {'string':'endpoints', 'model': Endpoint},
            {'string':'scenes', 'model': Scene},
            {'string':'actions', 'model': Action},
            {'string':'smart_scenes', 'model': SmartScene},
            {'string':'buttons', 'model': Button},
            {'string':'button_actions', 'model': ButtonAction},
        ]
        for item in context_dict:
            for key, value in item.items():
                if key == 'string':
                    string = value
                else:
                    model = value
            context[string] = model.objects.filter(config_id__exact=self.kwargs['config_id'])
        return context
```

Comment: I think this is the issue but I’m not sure how to solve it: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16335

Comment: `context[string] = ...` ?? string might be referenced before assignment

Answer (score 2):

By default, the context is rendered by a variable called `object_list`. So you can iterate like

```
{% for i in object_list %}
  // do something 
{% endfor %}
```

You can override the variable name by defining `context_object_name` attribute on a generic view, which specifies the context variable to use

```
class MyView(ListView):
    ...
    ...
    context_object_name = "context"
```

Comment: Thanks, I have put this in my template but it yields nothing   
`{% for object in object_list %}
    <h2>{{ object }}</h2>`

Comment: I have got the following to work in Django shell but it doesn't work in the template (parentheses removed from items as per the docs)
`
 {% for object in object_list %}
    {% for key, value in object.items %}
      {% if key == 'string' %}
    <h2>{{ value }}</h2>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
`

Comment: @BasslineSoup In your case you are passing different keys for different queryset `context[string] = model.ob...` So you can access each queryset by that corresponding keys ('integrations', 'control_groups' etc...).

Comment: @BasslineSoup So you can iterate over the queryset in your template like  `{% for object in  integrations %} # do something {% endfor %} {% for object in  control_groups %} # do something {% endfor %}` and so on.....

Comment: thanks, that would likely work as I have written out a form of that without the for loops but it'd be much tidier if I can compact it all into one set of For loops that iterates through the whole object_list.  Is that simply not possible and I should stick to your suggestion?

Comment: @BasslineSoup Those are different queryset, Does these models have the same fields or different? Anyway, you can combine multiple queryset using `itertools.chain`. After that, you will only need to iterate over a single thing.

Comment: Can you please clarify where to use this?  Do you mean in my views instead of context_dict? Or somehow in my template?  Thanks

Comment: And to answer your previous question, they have different fields

Comment: @BasslineSoup If they have different fields then you cannot chain them together.

Comment: Thanks.  So does that mean what I want to do is not possible: iterate over object_list.items ??

Comment: Is there a way by which I can get both variable name and value of context?